# Best tool to plot "streamlines"?

Tags: python, plot, streamline

I wanna plot a velocity profile, this is what I have:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z319A.png)

but I want something like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGeP6.png)

Data set is X and Y coordinates (basically a grid, e.g. 256x256, containing every coordinate) 3rd column is velocity.

So far I only found out it's not achievable in Gnuplot so I suppose my next best option would be Python.
What would be the easiest way for this in python? I'm not even sure if what I need is indeed streamline plotting, I just want to achieve what is in the second photo attached.

Comment: [`contour`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) is what you're looking for. You can see examples [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html)

Comment: Thank you @AlexP, after a little more of googling I realized I can do streamline plotting in matplotlib but contour is also what I needed for another comparison. I guess I'll be making a new post as I haven't been able to find a streamline plotting solution from others posts.